# Cдал положительный допинг-тест

Tags: грамотная-речь

Интернет полон сообщений о том, что тот или иной спортсмен "сдал положительный допинг-тест". На мой взгляд это безграмотно. Результаты теста могут быть положительными, но как можно "сдать тест", да ещё если он к тому же положительный? Хотелось бы узнать мнение экспертов. Как правильно (и коротко!) выразить то, что результат теста на допинг оказался положительным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу большой проблемы. Да, есть некоторый налет разговорности, но не более.

Сдать тест — вообще никаких сомнений не вызывает (даже не пойму причину вашего неприятия), а вот то, что он положительный... Ну да, положительным оказался результат (не в хорошем смысле, естественно, положительным). Но не заставишь же каждого говорить "тест с положительным результатом", тем более, что у медиков есть масса подобных образований: от "положительной" реакции Вассермана до резус-фатора.

Я бы признал сочетание правильным.

(+)

Прочитал комментарий- совсем понимать перестал. Претензия, получается, даже не к тому, что положительный - это по результатам устанавливается... А к чему - не понимаю.

(++)

Последняя попытка что-то понять.

*Сдал тест, который после проверки оказался положительным.

Сдал тест, который впоследствии оказался положительным.

Сдал тест, который оказался положительным.

Сдал положительный тест.*

Начиная с какой фразы появляется неправильность?

Comment: Вообще-то тест - испытание, в отличие от реакции Вассермана (результат) и резус-фактора (характеристика). Допустим, можно говорить "сдать тест", как "сдать экзамен". Тогда это означает "подвергнуться испытанию" или "пройти испытание УСПЕШНО". Никак не вяжется с плохим результатом. Далее, если принять , что "тест" может употребляться в смысле "результат теста", то можно найти такие примеры как "ПОЛУЧИТЬ положительный тест на ВИЧ, на беременность", но не "СДАТЬ положительный тест на ВИЧ, на беременность".

Comment: *но не "СДАТЬ положительный тест на ВИЧ, на беременность"* - да помилуйте, почему? Нормальная ситуация. Анализ можно сдать? Тест - тот же анализ. Экзамен - да, тут можно сдать или не сдать, положительный - излишне. И при этом именно что как у Вассермана имеется в виду результат. "Сдал на базу плохой товар" - какие вопросы, тот же случай.

Comment: А допинг-проба? "Сдал положительную допинг-пробу"? Тоже нельзя?

Comment: На мой взгляд, "допинг-проба" делает фразу понятной. По-вашему "тест" был употреблен как синоним "пробы"? 
Кстати, google находит фразу "ПОЛУЧИЛ положительный тест на ВИЧ", но не находит "СДАЛ", а с положительным допинг-тестом все наоборот. Почему - не знаю.

Comment: *По-вашему "тест" был употреблен как синоним* Разумеется. Даже если не полный синоним, то сочетаемость абсолютно та же. Но вы ушли от вопроса. Про понятность фразы я вообще не спрашивал. Фраза понятна в любом случае. Вы же настаивает на **неправильности**. С "пробой" фраза перестала быть неправильной?

Comment: *Почему - не знаю* - а я вам высказал предположение, что причина ваших затруднений в том, что вы почему-то не можете перенести последующее свойство (по результату) на исходное. Вы от этой версии отмахнулись. Теперь вот недоумеваете по тому же самому поводу.

Comment: На неправильности больше не настаиваю. Признаю, что в разговорной речи "тест" можно употреблять вместо "проба", хотя в словарях этого не нашел. По сути это и есть ответ на мой исходный вопрос: скажите "Сдал положительную допинг-пробу"  - и все будет понятно и по словарю верно. А вот последний ваш комментарий а не понял. Почему про положительный тест на ВИЧ и на беременность все говорят "получил", а про положительный допинг-тест все говорят "сдал" (есло верить google)?

Comment: Так что же означает "положительный" для теста на допинг: допинг обнаружен или нет? Потому что положительный тест на вич означает что вич обнаружен. Что не есть хорошо (положительно).

Comment: "Так что же означает "положительный" для теста на допинг: допинг обнаружен или нет?" - Тут все однозначно. "Положительный тест на что-то" означает, что это "что-то" обнаружено.